# Text analysis: finding the most common word in a column using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a dataframe with just a column with the subject line.

```
df = activities.filter(['Subject'],axis=1)
df.shape
```

This returned this dataframe:

```
    Subject
0   Call Out: Quadria Capital - May Lo, VP
1   Call Out: Revelstoke - Anthony Hayes (Sr Assoc...
2   Columbia Partners: WW Worked (Not Sure Will Ev...
3   Meeting, Sophie, CFO, CDC Investment
4   Prospecting
```

I then tried to analyse the text with this code:

```
import nltk
top_N = 50
txt = df.Subject.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ')
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(txt)
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
words_except_stop_dist = nltk.FreqDist(w for w in words if w not in stopwords) 

rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N), columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
print(rslt)
```

The error message I get is: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Subject'

Comment: Try replacing `df.Subject` with just `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being thrown because you have converted `df` to a Series in this line:

```
df = activities.filter(['Subject'],axis=1)
```

So when you say:

```
txt = df.Subject.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ')
```

df is the Series and does not have the attribute Series. Try replacing with:

```
txt = df.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ')
```

Or alternatively don't filter your DataFrame to a single Series before and then

```
txt = df.Subject.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ')
```

should work.

[UPDATE]

What I said above is incorrect, as pointed out filter does not return a Series, but rather a DataFrame with a single column.

Comment: Thanks Dever, I tried the first option, and I got this error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'. The second option gave me this other error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: `activities.filter(['Subject'],axis=1)` doesn't return series. It returns dataframe with 1 column.

Comment: @Esther not sure why you are getting that error. I can do a similar operation as the line `txt = df.Subject.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ')` and do not receive an attribute error. I assume this is where your error is being thrown, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I think I need to dig a bit deeper here. There could be a problem with the file. We'll keep you posted!

Comment: @Esther: check for any `None`, `NaN`, or any non-String values in `df.Subject`

Answer (score 1):

### Data:

```py
Subject
"Call Out: Quadria Capital - May Lo, VP"
Call Out: Revelstoke - Anthony Hayes (Sr Assoc...
Columbia Partners: WW Worked (Not Sure Will Ev...
"Meeting, Sophie, CFO, CDC Investment"
Prospecting

# read in the data
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

[image]

### Updated code:

- Convert all words to lowercase and remove all non-alphanumeric characters

  - `txt = df.Subject.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ')` creates a `pandas.core.series.Series` and will be replaced
- `words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(txt)`, throws a `TypeError` because `txt` is a `Series`.

  - The following code tokenizes each row of the dataframe
- Tokenizing the words, splits each string into a `list`.  In this example, looking at `df` will show a `tok` column, where each row is a list

```py
import nltk
import pandas as pd

top_N = 50

# replace all non-alphanumeric characters
df['sub_rep'] = df.Subject.str.lower().str.replace('\W', ' ')

# tokenize
df['tok'] = df.sub_rep.apply(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize)
```

[image]

- To analyze all the words in the column, the individual rows lists are combined into a single list, called `words`.

```py
# all tokenized words to a list
words = df.tok.tolist()  # this is a list of lists
words = [word for list_ in words for word in list_]

# frequency distribution
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)

# remove stopwords
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
words_except_stop_dist = nltk.FreqDist(w for w in words if w not in stopwords)

# output the results
rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N), columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
```

#### Output `rslt`:

```
        Word  Frequency
        call          2
         out          2
     quadria          1
     capital          1
         may          1
          lo          1
          vp          1
  revelstoke          1
     anthony          1
       hayes          1
          sr          1
       assoc          1
    columbia          1
    partners          1
          ww          1
      worked          1
         not          1
        sure          1
        will          1
          ev          1
     meeting          1
      sophie          1
         cfo          1
         cdc          1
  investment          1
 prospecting          1
```