# Get a list with a value per line from Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas, list

[image: Example of my Dataframe]

I want to to the 'column of text' column into a list.  How do you turn each new line inside the cell into a value for a list.  I would normally use something like:

```
my_new_list = df.Column_of_text.tolist()
```

The problem with that is that I need each separate line inside of each cell a value in my new list.

Example of output I am expecting:

```
my_new_list =["Hey how is it going","good how are youI am fine thank y...", "Nice Weather today, eh?", etc...]
```

Any ideas on this?  It would be greatly appreciated.

I have noticed this has been marked as possible duplicate but this is not the case.  My question has nothing to do with getting the most popular words in a column...

Comment: [Pandas series.str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120996/text-analysis-finding-the-most-common-word-in-a-column-using-python/58121920#58121920

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text analysis: finding the most common word in a column using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120996/text-analysis-finding-the-most-common-word-in-a-column-using-python)

Comment: These _suggested_ duplicates have nothing to do with the original post. If you guys find a better one I'll close this ;)

Comment: @rafaelc totally agree.  Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `chain.from_iterable` + `str.split('\n')`

```
import itertools

my_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df['column_name'].str.split('\n')))
```

list comprehensions can also be a good idea here

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([text.split('\n') for text in df['column_name']]))
```

Comment: Imo you could achieve this from pandas 0.25 on without itertools via pd.Series.explode(). `df['column_name'].str.split('\n').explode()` if I remember correctly

Comment: @SpghttCd Even though that works, it is way slower than itertools and a list comprehension :)

Comment: I am getting 'float' object is not iterable error... any thoughts?

Comment: @rafaelc it works now.  I have numbers in my real example so I just had to convert the column to a str.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of lists.

```
my_new_list = []
for i in df.Column_of_text:
    n = i.split('\n')
    my_new_list.append(n)
```

You can then use.

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_new_list))
```

@rafeleac s way is more concise though.

Comment: This is kind of identical to my answer

Comment: Yeah, already posted the way to make the list of lists. Then realized it was a list of lists. Was looking up the command to combine them when I came back I saw your answer was there. Did the second edit to give preference to your answer.